# ng-click not working on dynamic added DIV by jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Following code is added after page renders on DOM by jquery.

```
owldata = '<div class="item"><div class="ifl-removepic" ng-click="deleteDocument("'+e.target.result+'");"></div><img src="' + e.target.result + '"></div>';
```

In this **deleteDocument(string)** function is not getting called which is defined in respective controller.
Is this because of this html code is written in .js file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it 1st to make `ng-click` to work.

```
var owldata = angular.element(
            '<div class="item"><div class="ifl-removepic" ng-click="deleteDocument("'+e.target.result+'");"></div><img src="' + e.target.result + '"></div>'
            );

owldata = $compile(owldata)($scope);
angular.element(some_root).append(owldata);
```

Comment: Can you help me out how can we use $compile in my case?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the code is added dynamically, you need to recompile it:

```
$compile(divElement);
```

First you need to add $compile to your app of course